# KDE Plasma - disable right click "as select" in context menus

Tags: ubuntu, kde, gui, plasma

I'm using KDE Plasma (Kubuntu 18.04). I notice when you right click to bring up a context menu, it is possible to select the options with left click OR right click. I find this behavior quite troublesome as if I quickly right click twice, its possible to accidentally select close and close the window. Is it possible to set KDE Plasma to only accept left click to select options via context menus?

Thanks for any help

Comment: For reference: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=430014

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know - the only way is to code it your self. Which means - no. Sadly. I really believe that should not work the way it works - meaning - right click should not mean selecting an option. But so far, and as far as I know - nope.